# Combining two liquids with different weights to achieve a desired volume and weight

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, volume

I have two liquids - water and alcohol, each liquid has a different mass

- Water weighs 1 gram per ML
- Alcohol weighs 0.5 gram per ML (just for the sake of the example)

I wish to combine these liquids using a yet to be determined ratio to produce a volume of 2mls and a total mass of 1.75grams

I think my formula is this -

```
 1      0.5     1.75
---  +  ---  =  ---
 x       y       2
```

Is my formula correct? And is there a technique for solving this?

Comment: This question assumes that in mixing liquids total volume is preserved (just like total mass), although that is not always true in reality. In [particular for water and alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_molar_property#mediaviewer/File:Excess_Volume_Mixture_of_Ethanol_and_Water.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the amount of milliliters of water.

Let $y$ denote the amount of milliliters of alcohol.

Then you want:

- $x+y=2$
- $1x+0.5y=1.75$

This is a system of two equations with two variables, easy to solve:

- $x+y=2 \implies x=2-y$
- $1x+0.5y=1.75 \implies x=1.75-0.5y$
- $[x=2-y]\wedge[x=1.75-0.5y] \implies 2-y=1.75-0.5y$
- $2-y=1.75-0.5y \implies 0.5y=0.25 \implies y=0.5$
- $[x+y=2]\wedge[y=0.5] \implies x+0.5=2 \implies x=1.5$

Comment: It took me a long time to understand this and I had to do a bit of reading elsewhere but I get it now. My next challenge is to put the formula into an Excel spreadsheet so that I can specify the desired volume and weight and have it figure out X and Y for me dynamically based on the input. Do you know how to translate such an equation into something Excel could understand? Could you point me in the right direction? I'm aware of Solver, but this seems to be the kind of thing you run once for each individual equation where as I need it to run the equation for a long list of inputs.